# Provide and Protect a Read Only PDF on Website

Tags: security, pdf, readonly, acrobat, privacy

I have a client who wants to provide a PDF document on their website but they want to ensure that the document is protected from being downloaded. I've looked at some js plugins that provide readers, but it seems like a quick look at the source code will reveal the path to the PDF in most cases. Anyone have experience with this or know how it can be done?

Comment: In order to display a PDF in a browser, you have to provide the PDF file to the browser.  Even if you somehow hide the path to the file, the user can still save the displayed PDF.

Comment: With questions like these, it's worth adding some background information as to what you are doing (selling books?) and explaining why you want to do something (ensure people pay for your books?). That will allow people to make suggestions - as the answer from @user3553031 says, you could just rasterise the PDF and render that to the screen until the user purchases it, at which point you can release the full thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow people to view the documents but make it hard for them to copy them, you'll need to do the document rendering server-side.  Keep track of the user's viewport (size, zoom, coordinates in the document, etc.), render the portion of the document within the viewport as a static image, and send that to the user.  Keep in mind that no matter what you do, users can reassemble the document if they put enough effort into it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any ideas about where I could go to find some resources on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The "normal" approach is to not bother about not allowing to download, but to make the documents usable only under certain conditions. This essentially means some kind of DRM (Digital Rights Management) system.

You can for example have the document call home and ask for permission to be opened, or printed. You can also tie the file to the user's hard disk (via signature), etc.

With document security, you (your client) has to decide how much it is worth to you/him. That will also set the budget for a DRM system.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any articles or tutorials for how to do that with a PDF?